# What size rear axle and cones for 1999 Schwinn Cruiser 6?

Tags: axle, cones

What size rear axle and cones fit a 1999 Schwinn Cruiser 6 bicycle. I cannot find a part number or identifier, is it the same size as BMX parts?

Comment: Easiest way is to take the old axle and cones to a LBS.  Generally you need an axle wide enough, and a right-hand cone that will fit, but most other things are the same.   Do fit new bearings too - its false economy to reuse the old ones.